# How Do I copy values from Difference to Actual amount column

Tags: python, selenium

Here is my HTML:

```
<div style="height: 410px; overflow: hidden; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 154px; width: 1338px;"><div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px;"><div class="v-customcomponent v-customcomponent-gk-grid gk-grid" style="width: 1338px; height: 410px;"><div class="v-table" style="width: 1338px;"><div class="v-table-header-wrap" style="width: 1336px;"><div class="v-table-header" style="overflow: hidden;"><div style="width: 900000px;"><table><tbody><tr><td class="v-table-header-cell" style="width: 308px;"><div class="v-table-resizer"></div><div class="v-table-sort-indicator"></div><div class="v-table-caption-container" style="width: 290px;">Tenders</div></td><td class="v-table-header-cell" style="width: 196px;"><div class="v-table-resizer"></div><div class="v-table-sort-indicator"></div><div class="v-table-caption-container" style="width: 178px;">Currency</div></td><td class="v-table-header-cell" style="width: 151px;"><div class="v-table-resizer"></div><div class="v-table-sort-indicator"></div><div class="v-table-caption-container v-table-caption-container-align-right" style="width: 134px;">Count</div></td><td class="v-table-header-cell" style="width: 281px;"><div class="v-table-resizer"></div><div class="v-table-sort-indicator"></div><div class="v-table-caption-container v-table-caption-container-align-right" style="width: 264px;">Actual Amount</div></td><td class="v-table-header-cell" style="width: 218px;"><div class="v-table-resizer"></div><div class="v-table-sort-indicator"></div><div class="v-table-caption-container v-table-caption-container-align-right" style="width: 201px;">Difference</div></td><td class="v-table-header-cell" style="width: 182px;"><div class="v-table-resizer"></div><div class="v-table-sort-indicator"></div><div class="v-table-caption-container v-table-caption-container-align-right" style="width: 164px;">Amount  </div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="v-table-column-selector" style="display: none;"></div></div><div tabindex="-1" class="v-scrollable v-table-body-wrapper v-table-body" style="zoom: 1; position: relative; overflow: auto; width: 1336px; height: 383px;"><div style="height: 383px;"><div class="v-table-row-spacer" style="height: 0px;"></div><table class="v-table-table"><tbody><tr class="v-selected v-table-row" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 294px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 294px;">Наличные</div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 182px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 182px;"> </div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 137px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 137px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 267px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 267px;"><input type="text" class="v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right" maxlength="12" style="width: 249px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 204px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 204px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 168px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 168px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row-odd" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 294px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 294px;">Maestro OFF</div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 182px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 182px;"> </div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 137px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 137px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 267px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 267px;"><input type="text" class="v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right" maxlength="12" style="width: 249px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 204px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 204px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 168px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 168px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 294px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 294px;">American Express OFF</div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 182px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 182px;"> </div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 137px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 137px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 267px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 267px;"><input type="text" class="v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right" maxlength="12" style="width: 249px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 204px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 204px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 168px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 168px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row-odd" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 294px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 294px;">MasterCard OFF</div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 182px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 182px;"> </div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 137px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 137px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 267px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 267px;"><input type="text" class="v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right" maxlength="12" style="width: 249px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 204px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 204px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 168px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 168px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 294px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 294px;">Visa Card OFF</div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 182px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 182px;"> </div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 137px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 137px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 267px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 267px;"><input type="text" class="v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right" maxlength="12" style="width: 249px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 204px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 204px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 168px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 168px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row-odd" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 294px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 294px;">China Union Pay OFF</div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 182px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 182px;"> </div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 137px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 137px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 267px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 267px;"><input type="text" class="v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right" maxlength="12" style="width: 249px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 204px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 204px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 168px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 168px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 294px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 294px;">ALI PAY OFF</div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 182px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 182px;"> </div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 137px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 137px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 267px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 267px;"><input type="text" class="v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right" maxlength="12" style="width: 249px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 204px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 204px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 168px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 168px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row-odd" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 294px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 294px;">MIR</div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 182px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 182px;"> </div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 137px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 137px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 267px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 267px;"><input type="text" class="v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right" maxlength="12" style="width: 249px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 204px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 204px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 168px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 168px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 294px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 294px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 182px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 182px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 137px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 137px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 267px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 267px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 204px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 204px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 168px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 168px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row-odd" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 294px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 294px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 182px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 182px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 137px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 137px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 267px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 267px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 204px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 204px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 168px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 168px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 294px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 294px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 182px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 182px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 137px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 137px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 267px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 267px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 204px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 204px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 168px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 168px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row-odd" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 294px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 294px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 182px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 182px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 137px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 137px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 267px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 267px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 204px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 204px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 168px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 168px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 294px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 294px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 182px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 182px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 137px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 137px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 267px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 267px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 204px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 204px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 168px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 168px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row-odd" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 294px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 294px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 182px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 182px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 137px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 137px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 267px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 267px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 204px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 204px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 168px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 168px;"></div></td></tr><tr class="v-table-row" style=""><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 294px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 294px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 182px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 182px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 137px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 137px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 267px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 267px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 204px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 204px;"></div></td><td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 168px;"><div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 168px;"></div></td></tr></tbody></table><div class="v-table-row-spacer" style="height: 0px;"></div></div><div tabindex="0" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></div></div><div class="v-table-footer-wrap" style="display: none; width: 1336px;"><div class="v-table-footer" style="overflow: hidden;"><div style="width: 900000px;"><table><tbody><tr><td style="width: 307px;"><div class="v-table-footer-container" style="width: 293px;">&nbsp;</div></td><td style="width: 195px;"><div class="v-table-footer-container" style="width: 181px;">&nbsp;</div></td><td style="width: 150px;"><div class="v-table-footer-container" style="text-align: right; width: 136px;">&nbsp;</div></td><td style="width: 280px;"><div class="v-table-footer-container" style="text-align: right; width: 266px;">&nbsp;</div></td><td style="width: 217px;"><div class="v-table-footer-container" style="text-align: right; width: 203px;">&nbsp;</div></td><td style="width: 181px;"><div class="v-table-footer-container" style="text-align: right; width: 167px;">&nbsp;</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Can anyone please tell me ? many thanks

Comment: Elaborate your question and post the code what you have tried.

Comment: Read this first pls https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay so if we form the HTML, then we could copy values from Difference column to Actual amount column, like below :

**Code :**

```
k = 0
for write in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Actual Amount']/ancestor::div[@class='v-table-header-wrap']/following-sibling::div/descendant::input"):
    #ele = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"(//div[text()='Actual Amount']/ancestor::div[@class='v-table-header-wrap']/following-sibling::div/descendant::input)[{j}]")))
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(write).perform()
    write.clear()
    write.send_keys(difference_amount[k])
    k = k + 1
```